# How to read the output of a Linux command using JNA

Tags: java, jna

I want to call Linux ***mount*** command in java using JNA and populate a list of mount points from the call result but cannot understand what should be the actual return type for the interface method.

If I use int then it prints -1 without any errors. Which I think is an indication of some sort of error.

```
public class MountTest {

private interface CLibrary extends Library {
    String[] mount();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("c", CLibrary.class);

    System.out.println(INSTANCE.mount());
}
```

}

I tried to use different return types based on the below doc but nothing works.

[Default Type Mappings](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/Mappings.md#default-type-mappings)

I think my problem is the incorrect signature based on

> [My library sometimes causes a VM crash](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#my-library-sometimes-causes-a-vm-crash): Double check the signature of the method causing the crash to ensure all arguments are of the appropriate size and type. Be especially careful with native pointer variations. See also information on debugging structure definitions.

Could anyone help me on this. What return type should I use so that I can get access to the list of mount points.

**Update:**
I was able to run a Linux command by tweaking the code as below:

```
public class MountTest {

private interface CLibrary extends Library {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("c", CLibrary.class);
    int runCommand(String cmd);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CLibrary.INSTANCE.runCommand("mount");
}
```

}

Now, the problem is, Its printing to the stdout. I don't know how to read the result from stdout using JNA

Comment: How about calling the mount function directly, using JNA, and looking at its return value (int) to determine if it was successful: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html

Comment: What I want is the list of all currently attached file systems which is actually list of known mount points. I don't thing the return value would help in this case

Answer (score 0):

By [mount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) documentation

> mount() attaches the filesystem specified by source (which is often a
>          pathname referring to a device, but can also be the pathname of a
>          directory or file, or a dummy string) to the location (a directory or
>          file) specified by the pathname in target.

It means that `mount` syscall just mount directories, it's different from [the mount command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html). You are probably looking for [getmetent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getmntent.3.html), it will list all your filesystem mount points, a implementation bellow:

```
public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("c", CLibrary.class);
    Pointer fopen(String name, String mode);
    Mount.ByReference getmntent(Pointer FILE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Pointer mountFile = CLibrary.INSTANCE.fopen("/etc/mtab", "r");
    if (mountFile == null) {
        System.err.println("File not exists: " + mountFile);
        return;
    }
    Mount.ByReference mpoint;
    while ((mpoint = CLibrary.INSTANCE.getmntent(mountFile)) != null) {
        System.out.println(mpoint);
    }

}

public static class Mount extends Structure {
    public String mnt_fsname;
    public String mnt_dir;
    public String mnt_type;
    public String mnt_opts;
    public int mnt_freq;
    public int mnt_passno;

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        List<String> fieds = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final Field f : Mount.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (!f.isSynthetic())
                fieds.add(f.getName());
        }
        return fieds;
    }

    public static class ByReference extends Mount implements Structure.ByReference {
    }
}
```

**Obs:** As I know you cannot call compiled programs from JNA, just library functions and system calls, then is impossible to call mount command, if you really want to use this command then you probably want to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` or something like that.

---

update

Take a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3587/117844) there you can differentiate what is a program and what is a syscall or library function